# Elasticsearch doesn't obey _mapping after reindex

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a field called *last_post_date* stored in elasticsearch.

It's shown as:

```
...
"last_post_date": "1485281760000",
...
```

And has the mapping as:

```
"last_post_date": {
    "type": "text",
    "fields": {
        "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
        }
    }
},
```

Now I create a new index with the mapping as:

```
...
"last_post_date": {
    "type": "date",
    "format": "epoch_millis",
    "index": true,
    "doc_values": true
},
...
```

And do a full reindex via:
http://127.0.0.1:9200/_reindex

The problem is that even after reindexing the field's value is stored as string instead of date while the mapping shows:

```
...
"last_post_date": {
    "type": "date",
    "store": true,
    "format": "epoch_millis"
},
...
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you see in the source, i.e. a string-like timestamp of the form `"1485281760000"` will not change and will always reflect the exact same JSON you sent to Elasticsearch.

However, when being indexed, the string `"1485281760000"` will be indeed interpreted and indexed as the long value `1485281760000`.

If you were to change the JSON source you're sending with a long timestamp instead of a string timestamp, like below, then the source will show your a long timestamp.

```
...
"last_post_date": 1485281760000,
...
```

Long story short:

- what you see in the `_source` is exactly what you sent to ES
- each field of the source is interpreted and indexed according to the mapping you've created, i.e. the string timestamp will be coerced to a long and interpreted as a date of the format `epoch_millis`
- if some field value cannot be properly interpreted, indexed, coerced according to your mapping, you'll get an error and the document won't be indexed at all.

Comment: Wow, actually sorting works now so I think you are right! Thanks for the info.