# ElasticSearch convert string to number using dymanic mapping

Tags: elasticsearch

There is my elastic search mapping:

```
   "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "totalAmount": {
          "type": "integer"
        }
      },
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "strings_as_longs": {
            "match_mapping_type": "string",
            "match": "*Amount",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "integer"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

The purpose is store all fields, which contains **amount** as number. After applying this mapping to elastic there is such result:

```
  "totalAmount" : {
        "type" : "integer"
   }
```

I'm sending data to elastic in JSON format, but all numbers are represented as strings:

```
"freeAmount": "10",
"totalAmount": "60"
```

After retrieving I've got these numbers as strings also. It's strange for me, I thought elastic has to convert strings to numbers before saving and then give me them as numbers.
Should elastic convert them, or should I convert all needed data before saving to elastic?

Comment: Here is your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42429957/4604579

Comment: So in other words, all fields are stored in right format, but if I wanna get them as numbers, I should send them as numbers as well, right?

Comment: Correct, ES will never change what you send in the `_source`... unless you use an [ingest pipeline + convert processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/convert-processor.html) and have ES explicitly modify the document just before indexing it, but if you can do it in your client indexing code, you should do it.